# ProgressBar isn't shown on one particular screen in Xiaomi

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I have an application on android. In it I have a base activity with *drawer* and *toolbar*, this activity also contains *progress bar* and *dimmed layout* used by all the inheritors to display loading.

When I run the app on `Xiaomi` or `Huawei` phone (both `Android 6.0.1`), it works in all activities except one, and I can't figure out why. The dimmed layout is shown, but there's no progress bar. I tried to put progress bar into that activity, but it isn't shown anyway. When I run on emulator, everything's fine in all API's.

How it is:
[image: Picture]

How it should be (pay attention at the blue loading progress bar):
[image: How it should be]

The layout of the base activity:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/view_toolbar"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"/>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
                layout="@layout/view_drawer"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>    
    </LinearLayout>

    <View android:id="@+id/dimmed_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/main_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Activities-inheritors use progress bar and dimmed layout as following:

```
//Show loading:
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mDimmedBackground.setAlpha((float) 0.3);

//Hide loading:
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
mDimmedBackground.setAlpha((float) 0);
```

The activity where it doesn't work has the following layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">    

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/view_padding_small"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: try to change the theme of pthe ProgressBar

Comment: @Saret tried :(

Comment: @annaoomph did you find solution for this ?